# Wordpress customizer extremely slow, cant work in it

Tags: themes, theme-customizer

I have been adding a couple of settings to my Wordpress admin using this code:

```
$wp_customize->add_section( 'sectionname' , array(
        'title'      => __'Name',
        'priority'   => 80,
    ) );
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'settingsname' );
$wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Customize_Control(
        $wp_customize,
        'settingsname',
        array(
            'label'          => 'Text',
            'section'        => 'sectionname',
            'type'           => 'number',
        )
    )
);
```

Now the customizer is extremely, after i click a tab in the left handside menu, it freezes and after 30 seconds it loads what was clicked. No errors appears, and everything seems fine, except it is too slow.

I have tried increasing the memory on the server, and it is not that.

The super weird thing is that it is only in Chrome. I have tried this on multiple computers, on chrome it is all the same problem. But when using firefox it works fine.

Any pointers of what it can be would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: are you using query monitor?  that can be pretty helpful for debugging speed issues.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that it seems to be front end related. It is slow after everything has loaded. Maybe a better way of putting it is that it is slow to interact with. Every click seem to freeze the ui and then finally it registers the click and execute the action